# VueJs CreateElement() insert dynamic html

Tags: javascript, vue.js, createelement

I building a component to convert all icons to SVG.

So, at the end of my code I have this:

```
     return createElement('i',
        '<SVG>CODE</SVG>'
      )
```

Where is this SPAN, I should add a dynamic HTML! 
I could not find any option to do it. This HTML will be an SVG, so, for this reason, I need to add the full HTML.

Somebody had the same problem?
What is missing?? How to make this  as new HTML, when my component is running???

> **ps:** I dont need to know how to create a SVG file, but yes, how render the HTML, that can be anyone, inside of my dynamic component.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3492322

Comment: I already have my SVG content. I just need to find a way to render my HTML as HTML and as STRING.

Comment: Perhaps like this `<div v-html="my_svg_string"></div><div>{{ my_svg_string }}</div>` ?

Comment: Have you looked at [`v-html`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html)?

Comment: is a dynamic element. I think that I can't do that.

I found what I need. I should add an attribute: 
domProps: {innerHTML: this.data}

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Don't edit your question to include the word "solved".

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution!

```
return createElement('i', {
          domProps: {
            innerHTML: this.data
          }
        }
      )
```