# How to set component property programmatically in Vuetify component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a checkbox component defined like so:

```
let checkbox = this.$createElement(VCheckbox, {
    props: {
        hideDetails: true
    }
});
```

In my code I can get a reference to this component. In other words I have access to this `checkbox` variable. What I want is to set property programmatically. By property I mean this part of the component:

```
props: {
    hideDetails: true
}
```

What I want is to set `indeterminate` to true. Something like:

```
checkbox.setProperty('indeterminate', true);
```

But I'm unable to find in documenation anything related to my problem. So, how can I implement this?

Comment: `this.hideDetails = true` is not working ?

Comment: No, it is not..

Comment: So why you don't create a dynamic variable in data ? `hideDetails: this.state`

Comment: @John. Nice tip, I will check it in a minute.

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?

Comment: Are you trying to use $createElement to build a Vue component or are u using it inside an existing component? All $createElement does is create DOM elements, not Vue components. Meaning, you can't add Vue properties to regular DOM elements.. [Here](https://codepen.io/dchanis/pen/XEBVXg?editors=1010) ([taken from here](https://medium.com/@dillonchanis/leveraging-render-props-in-vue-7eb9a19c262d)) is an example of render functions, and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51502183/vuejs-createelement-insert-dynamic-html) is an example of adding DOM props using $createElement.

Comment: @John, it solved

Comment: @Matt. I do not want to add anything to DOM elements

Comment: @Jacobian you solved with my way ? if yes I have to make a answer to close this question

Comment: @Jacobian then a render function is what you're after. Look into functional components.

Comment: @John, it solved with your way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a dynamic variable in your data scope :

```
data: function() {
  return {
    stateDetails: true
  };
}
```

Then use it in your props :

```
props: {
  hideDetails: this.stateDetails
}
```

And now you can change the value like that :

```
this.stateDetails = true / false
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
let checkbox = this.$createElement(VCheckbox, {
    ref:"refToElement",
    props: {
        hideDetails: true
    }
});
    this.$refs.refToElement.$el.setProperty('indeterminate', true);
```

Comment: I do not want to use a template. Therefore, I clearly said how this component is created in my code. It is created by `this.$createElement`. And I need to set property on the fly, otherwise, I would just have another `props` inside `this.$createElement` statement

Comment: Basically, I need to know if there is something similar to `setProperty` method

Comment: checkbox.$el.setProperty('indeterminate', true);

Comment: It is not working. And by the way, you are trying to set a property of DOM element. It is not right.

Comment: can you try once again with ref