# How to create an svg element programmatically in an svg document?

Tags: svg

I know that we can use the `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg","line");` to create a svg element embeded in a html page.

But, this method doesn't seems to work in a standalone svg document.

Actually, I am trying to draw the national flag of India in svg, but, drawing the 24 spokes in the wheel of the flag would be very time consuming. So, I thought of drawing them programmatically through JavaScript.

Any help on how to create elements programmatically in a standalone svg document will be appreciated.

Comment: createElementNS takes 2 arguments, the first is the SVG namespace.

Comment: Oh ! Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use javascript inside an svg element. I've done only the center of the flag. 
Please observe the `viewBox="-50 -50 100 100"`. The point {x:0,y:0} is in the center of the SVG canvas.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:90vh;}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="-50 -50 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
   
  <g id="center" fill="blue" stroke="blue">
  <circle r="5" />
  <circle id="outline" stroke-width="4" fill="none" r="48" />
  <polygon id="spoke" points="0,0 20,1.5 48,0 20,-1.5 0,0" fill="blue" stroke="none" />
  <circle id="dot" r="2.5" cx="46" transform="rotate(7.5)"  />
  </g>
  
    <script>
        <![CDATA[
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';


// a function that creates a new `<use>` element and rotates it around the origin of the SVG canvas
function reuse(used,parent,i) {  
let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', used); use.setAttributeNS(null,"transform" ,`rotate(${360*i/24})`);
parent.appendChild(use);
}
// a loop that creates 24 use elements
for(let i = 0;i < 24; i++ ){
reuse("#spoke",document.querySelector("#center"),i);
reuse("#dot",document.querySelector("#center"),i);
}
        ]]> 
  </script>
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, but I could not understand actually which part of the code is adding a shape.

Comment: In SVG you can [reuse elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use). All I am drawing are the two circles one spoke and one dot.The spoke and the dot are reused 24 times and rotated. for making thinks easier I've written the function `reuse(used,parent,i)` where `used` is a string representing the `id` of the reused element, the parent is the element where I'm appending the new `<use>` element and `i` is the index - used to rotate the element.

Comment: Thanks for explaning. Now I will be able to create a vector graphics of the India flag.

Comment: Is there any technique to create svg elements programmatically ?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand you. In my example I've created `<use>` elements. What kind of elements do you want to create?

Comment: Just like in HTML we can create any element dynamically, I want to create the 'rect', 'circle' and other elements which are supported in svg. How to do that ?

Comment: In SVG you use [document.createElementNS()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElementNS). If you have a concrete example please ask a different question. I'll be glad to help. Meanwhile if you think that I've answered your question please accept my answer. This example may help you: [JavaScript createElement and SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492322/javascript-createelement-and-svg)

Comment: Thanks for your response and help. I learnt many things. Have a nice day :)

Answer (score -1):

You can't do what you're trying to do since Javascript shouldn't be included in, and isn't understood or processed inside a SVG file.

Comment: But I know that we can use the <[CDATA[...]]> inside the <script> tags in svg document to execute JS code.