# How to `appendChild` an SVG file

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have `arrow.svg` file. In my `index.js` that is in vanilla JS, I want to `appendChild` this to a body. How do I do that?

```
const theSVGFile = //... read from './arrow.svg'
document.getElementById('some-id').appendChild(theSVGFile);
```

Comment: You can set the path of the SVGfile to the src of an img tag. ex: <img src="svgroute" />

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript createElement and SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492322/javascript-createelement-and-svg) This works you can appendChild when you create a SVG element

Answer (score 0):

An example of Zoilo's suggestion which is generally the easiest route but reality is he deserves the credit since he beat me to it.

```js
const daSVGHost = document.createElement("img");
daSVGHost.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVW9D.jpg"; // SVG HERE

document.getElementById('testerooni').appendChild(daSVGHost);
```

```html
<div id="testerooni"></div>
```