# Load svg from file using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have searched the web but the answers showing embedding the SVG into the HTML using `<object>`, `<img>`, etc. What I want to do is open a large SVG file that contains lots of images, find the image I need, and show only that image on the page. How can I do that?

File structure is:

- directory

  - index.html
  - script.js
  - images.svg

Comment: `find the image I need` how do you do this? by the way I suggest using a backend templating language.

Comment: I would guess its a sprite.

Comment: @Weilory It has lots of child `<g>` elements under the `<svg> element, and each `g` element has a `label` attribute with the name of the image, so I can find the image I want by that name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few steps:

1. Use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to get the image data.
2. Use a [DOM parser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/DOMParser) to parse the XML into a document.
3. Find the SVG subset you want.  (You didn't show us your XML, but this is likely as simple as [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).)
4. Create an SVG element.  (This is actually a bit tricky due to the namespace.  See also:  [JavaScript createElementNS and SVG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3492322/362536))
5. [Append it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) to the relevant element on your page.

Comment: [Or do it with a Web Component](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)

Answer (score -2):

hello damn i think you can add svg in your html code and run code but you cant font-size svg in css you can use width and height in svg to big font-size ok under